# selenium using get(url) lose all cookies, login session

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having problems with the get(url) function.

First I used get(url) , then signed into my account. The problem came when i used get(url) to go to a different url, I found myself logged out.

Basically saying, whenever i use get(url), all the data/cookies disappeared.

Does anyone know how to keep data/cookies when you change url with get()?
I would appreciate if the solution would be in Python, thanks.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# for private reason, I removed the url
url = 'www.abcdefg.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

#i removed some code that insert user name, password, and ENTER ...

# wait till something appear 
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "goods-block")))

driver.get('www.abcdefg.com/1234abcd')
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add your code in post

Comment: It's likely you aren't waiting for the cookies to be set.  If you just use a .get() function after clicking submit for your login the cookies will not be saved.  You can either use a sleep, or a webdriverwait to wait for an element to appear that only appears after you login.

Comment: thanks for your answers, i actually did use webdriverwait. I don't know what's the problem. Maybe i should try with different websites and see the results.

Comment: There are a few questions on SO about this. I don't think waiting helps. I'm starting to think this is a limitation of selenium. I don't know exactly how websites do it but I think session authentication information need not even be stored in a cookie, i.e. if you didn't click "Remember me." Haven't found a solution.